# Stored procedure naming convention issue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, naming-conventions, sql-server-2012

We put up a new SQL server 2012.

Every time we create a stored procedure the name of the stored procedure gets changed to the AD group name the developer is in and the developers username.

What is causing this and how can we rectify it?

Comment: specify the schema name in front of the stor proc name.  Post an example of what you're doing.

Comment: NETWORKNAME\username.nameofstoredprocedure

Comment: FYI - this is for all databases even databases that have not been setup with a particular schema.

Comment: "dbo" is the "automatically included" schema.  See example below.  Try creating your procedure with "dbo.MyProcedureName".......

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and safest way is to prefix with the schema e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_myProc
AS ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating your procedure with a schema name?

Most likely, you are doing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspMyProcedure]
```

At the very least, you should do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMyProcedure]
```

Below is a small example to show the functionality of naming with the schema name.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspGetVersion]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetVersion]

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetVersion]

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 'dbo Version : ' + @@VERSION

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO

EXEC [dbo].[uspGetVersion] 
GO


if not exists(select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name='LookupSchema')
BEGIN
    print 'Creating the schema : [LookupSchema]' 
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [LookupSchema] AUTHORIZATION dbo;')
END


if exists(select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name='LookupSchema')
BEGIN
print 'Schema Exists : [LookupSchema]' 
END



IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LookupSchema].[uspGetVersion]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [LookupSchema].[uspGetVersion]

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [LookupSchema].[uspGetVersion]

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 'LookupSchema Version : ' + @@VERSION

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [LookupSchema].[uspGetVersion] TO [public]
go

EXEC [LookupSchema].[uspGetVersion] 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

When user creates database object without schema name in CREATE statement it is created in default user schema.

There are two way to create objects owned by particular schema.

1   Explicitly identify schema name in CREATE statement

CREATE PROC [MySchema].[ProcName]

2   Set up default user schema and create database objects without schema name.

ALTER USER UserName WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = MySchema;

CREATE PROC [ProcName]